# Question about Rendering a stream in DirectShowNet

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

currently I have a disfigured avi file that a program of mine creates. I found out that by going into graphedit, i can refigure it correctly.

I found that if i do:

```
SourceFile(test1.avi) -> AVI Splitter -> ffdshow video encoder -> AVI Mux -> File Writer
```

i can get a video stream back that is correct.

Now I am trying to convert this into C# Directshow.Net program that i can just call.

I create a graph and i add in a SourceFilter from the video file i want converted, i add in a grabber, find and then add the ffdshow encoder, AVI Mux and then setOutputFileName().

```
{
        filename = textBox1.Text;
        IFilterGraph2 filter = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 MainGraph = new CaptureGraphBuilder2() as ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
        int result;
        result = MainGraph.SetFiltergraph(filter);

        IBaseFilter source;
        result = filter.AddSourceFilter(filename, filename, out source);

        ISampleGrabber samplegrabber = (ISampleGrabber)new SampleGrabber();
        IBaseFilter basegrab = (IBaseFilter)samplegrabber;

        AMMediaType media;
        media = new AMMediaType();
        media.majorType = MediaType.Video;
        media.subType = MediaSubType.RGB32;
        media.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
        result = samplegrabber.SetMediaType(media);

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(media);
        result = samplegrabber.SetBufferSamples(true);

        result = filter.AddFilter(basegrab, "filter");

        //MainGraph.RenderStream(null, null, source, basegrab, null);



        IMediaEvent mediaEvent;
        IMediaControl mediacontrol;
        mediaEvent = filter as IMediaEvent;
        mediacontrol = filter as IMediaControl;






        IntPtr hEvent;
        result = mediaEvent.GetEventHandle(out hEvent);

        ManualResetEvent mre;

        mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        mre.SafeWaitHandle = new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle(hEvent, true);

        //Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.EventWait));

        //mediacontrol.Run();

        object newsource = null;
        IBaseFilter encoder;

        Guid iid = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
        foreach (DsDevice device in DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoCompressorCategory))
        {
            if (device.Name.CompareTo("ffdshow video encoder") == 0)
            {
                device.Mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref iid, out newsource);
                break;
            }
        }

        encoder = (IBaseFilter)newsource;
object newsource2 = null;
        IBaseFilter encoder2;

        Guid iid2 = typeof(IBaseFilter).GUID;
        foreach (DsDevice device in DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.LegacyAmFilterCategory))
        {
            if (device.Name.CompareTo("AVI Mux") == 0)
            {
                device.Mon.BindToObject(null, null, ref iid2, out newsource2);
                break;
            }
        }

        encoder2 = (IBaseFilter)newsource2;
        result = filter.AddFilter(encoder, "encoder");
        result = filter.AddFilter(encoder2, "Avi Mux");


        FileWriter file = new FileWriter();
        IFileSinkFilter fs = (IFileSinkFilter)file;
        IBaseFilter mux;
        IFileSinkFilter sink;
        Guid cat;
        Guid med;
  cat = PinCategory.Capture;
        med = MediaType.Video;


        //result = filter.AddFilter(encoder, "encoder");
        result = MainGraph.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Avi, "C:\\Users\\Caleb\\Desktop\\conversion.avi", out mux, out sink);

        result = MainGraph.RenderStream( cat,  med, source, null, mux);
mediacontrol.Run();

}
```

this code creates the same graph to my knowledge. It creates my file, but doesnt convert anything. The file it creates is 0bytes. Am i doing renderstream wrong or some other error in my code?

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a decompressed avi file? You may need a huge hard drive for this...

Comment: i need to start somewhere. the file i create originally is decompressed avi but the colors are screwed up because the video never got encoded correctly so i do that here. when that works then i can decompress it

Comment: It sounds like a good plan. Please remember that you do not need to add the avi muxer explicitly on the graph when you use 'SetOutputFileName', since it will be added for you by this function and it will be returned in the 'mux' parameter.

Comment: problem is, this code only generates a file. it doesnt do anything into that file and im trying to figure out why

Comment: Side note. MSDN: "Do not close the event handle returned by the `IMediaEvent.GetEventHandle` method, because the event handle is used internally by the filter graph." In other words, do not use `SafeWaitHandle(hEvent, true)`, but use `SafeWaitHandle(hEvent, false)` instead. It will help to avoid problems in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i put in a piece of code:

```
DsRotEntry m_rot = new DsRotEntry(filter);
```

this allowed me to view my filter i made, in graphedit.

what happened was i add the filters but none of them got connected to each other.

So then what i did was got each of the filters i added, found the input and output pins associated with them

```
Filter2.FindPin( "name of the input pin here", out pinName);
Filter1.FindPin( "name of the output pin here", out PinName2);

MainFilter.connect( PinName2, pinName);
```

this created a connection between the filters. I wasnt doing this and i did this and now im getting closer to what i want.

so basically for Directshow.net and DirectShowNet-Lib it programs like

```
find a filter -> add a filter -> find a filter -> add a filter -> find the pins -> connect the pins -> run
```

Comment: other then the fact that this code doubles the size of the original video ( 10sec/1gig   -> 10sec/2gig) it works perfectly. Now i just need to make a decompressor in it